How to set up mailboxes on a subdomain with a CNAME record pointing to Zoho Desk?
I have a subdomain that is currently redirected to Zoho Desk using a CNAME record. I want to create mailboxes on this subdomain, but I understand that to do this in DirectAdmin, I need to set up the subdomain as a main domain, which requires an A record instead of just a CNAME.
How can I configure my DNS to allow both the Zoho Desk redirection and the creation of mailboxes on this subdomain? Is there a workaround to achieve both?
